# Will the Localstorage clear the entire localstrorage in production app

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage

I basically have two questions reguarding local staorage.

1. If i use `localstorage.clear()` in my producation application will it wipe out the entire localstorage from the browser. If the local storage had some content from other application.
2. If i user local storage for my application will the user be able to see or clear it even if the user is not currently using my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `localStorage.clear()` removes everything stored in it, and same goes for `sessionStorage`, but it's per domain/page, not per browser. This means if 3rd parts script in the same page/domain store stuff in it, you are removing their stuff too.
2. users can always clear their whole browser cache and affect your local storage data, unless your application runs with its own WebView (phonegap, cordova, native apps). If this is a regular Web App, users can always read content, or even modify it, through devtools.

The TL;DR is that `localStorage` is not a good storage solution, it's not secure, and it's ultimately not reliable.

Strawberry on top, it's synchronous, hence blocking, and limited in size.

I suggest IndexedDB instead, and yet malicious code could interfere with its data too, and users can read it, so I'd never store passwords in there.